# Conversion of an equation into differential form

Tags: integration, derivatives

I have the following equation
$u(l)=\frac{\gamma cos(\theta)}{4\mu r(l)^3\int_{0}^{l}{r(x)^{-4}}dx}$
taken from a research paper.
The author converts this equation into the form
$\frac{d[r(l)u(l)^{1/3}]}{dl}=-\frac{4u(l)^{4/3}}{3\alpha}$ using Leibnitz rule. Can someone please explain how is this conversion done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be done in this way. Rewrite the equation as
$$
r^3u=\frac{\alpha}{4\int_{0}^lr^{-4}(x)dx}
$$
where I set $\alpha=\gamma\cos(\theta)/\mu$. Then,
$$
ru^\frac{1}{3}=\left(\frac{\alpha}{4\int_{0}^lr^{-4}(x)dx}\right)^\frac{1}{3}.
$$
Taking the derivative gives
$$
\frac{d(ru^\frac{1}{3})}{dl}=-\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{\alpha}{4}\right)^\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{\int_{0}^lr^{-4}(x)dx}\right)^\frac{4}{3}r^{-4}.
$$
Finally, use again the first equation on the rhs and you are done.